# Python3 Timestamp to unix time (with sometime milliseconds)

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to convert a timestamp to unix time.

Timestamp looks like this:
*2018-01-16T20:26:16.35*

So now I use this code:

```
timestamp = '2018-01-16T20:26:16.35'
ts = timestamp.replace("T", " ")
tsUnix = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())
```

Sometime the api where get the timestamps from gives me the time **without milliseconds**.
 It will result in a error, 'Does not match the format'. (Duh, %f is not in there)

Do I need to script a workaround or is there a function for this? And is there a better way to strip the "T" from the original timecode?

Comment: Use a `try`/`except` block. Try the format with the milliseconds, catch the exception and try the format without.

Comment: I don't think you need to strip the 'T'. You can simply specify the 'T' in the pattern like so: `tsUnix = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())`

Comment: Thanks using the 'T' in there also worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to handle your issue, using `try` and `except`:

```
import time
import datetime

def get_ts_unix(ts):
    try:
        tsUnix = time.mktime(
            datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple()
        )
    except ValueError:
        tsUnix = time.mktime(
            datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").timetuple()
        )
    return tsUnix
```

Example:

```
timestamps = ['2018-01-16T20:26:16.35', '2018-01-16T20:26:16']
for ts in timestamps:
    print("%-24s: %f" % (ts, get_ts_unix(ts)))
```

Output:

```
2018-01-16T20:26:16.35  : 1516152376.000000
2018-01-16T20:26:16     : 1516152376.000000
```

Comment: Cool, yeah that's working! I also made this workaround:
`if '.' not in ts:
                    ts += '.0'`

Answer (score 0):

To skip the `ts = timestamp.replace("T", " ")` add a T in the format string

```
timestamp = '2018-01-16T20:26:16.35'
time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())
# returns 1516130776.0
```

To fix the milliseconds you could use the python-dateutil package

```
from dateutil import parser

raw_timestamp = '2018-01-16T20:26:16.35'
parsed_time = parser.parse(raw_timestamp)
timestamp = parsed_time.timestamp()
```